# How to find Key and IV value from .Net to PHP

Tags: php, .net, encryption

Can any one please let me know is there any way to find a solution for the below stuffs. I need to find out the KEY and IV value from the below byte array. the byte array in .net and this has to be convert into KEY(string) and IV(string) via PHP.

```
private static readonly byte[] Key = {
                                                0xda, 0x3c, 0x35, 0x6f, 0xbd, 0xd, 0x87, 0xf0,
                                                0x9a, 0x7, 0x6d, 0xab, 0x7e, 0x82, 0x36, 0xa,
                                                0x1a, 0x5a, 0x77, 0xfe, 0x74, 0xf3, 0x7f, 0xa8,
                                                0xaa, 0x4, 0x11, 0x46, 0x6b, 0x2d, 0x48, 0xa1
                                            };

        private static readonly byte[] IV =  {
                                                0x6d, 0x2d, 0xf5, 0x34, 0xc7, 0x60, 0xc5, 0x33,
                                                0xe2, 0xa3, 0xd7, 0xc3, 0xf3, 0x39, 0xf2, 0x16
                                            };
```

Comment: ...I really can't understand the question :)

Comment: Your question is not clear, as it does not contain enough information.  It looks as though you have provided some C# or C++ code which represents a byte array as produced by the RijndaelManaged GenerateIV and GenerateKey methods (or similar).  How are you reading these values into PHP?  What functions will be using these values in PHP?

Comment: Yes, that is what i need how to read those byte array values in PHP?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [characters in PHP are exactly one byte wide](http://us.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php), the closest equivalent to a .NET byte array in PHP is a string:

```
$Key = "\xda\x3c\x35\x6f\xbd\xd\x87\xf0\x9a\x7\x6d\xab\x7e\x82\x36\xa\x1a\x5a\x77\xfe\x74\xf3\x7f\xa8\xaa\x4\x11\x46\x6b\x2d\x48\xa1";
$IV = "\x6d\x2d\xf5\x34\xc7\x60\xc5\x33\xe2\xa3\xd7\xc3\xf3\x39\xf2\x16";
```

`Key.Length` becomes `strlen($Key)` and `Key[0]` becomes `$Key[0]`.